# Styling Thank You Page

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to style my Thank You page from a form submission. It must include:
- page background color
- border around the user profile image place holder
- one line above your user information and below your user information.

The Thank You page consists of three columns:
Column 1 is for the user profile image
Column 2 is for all form information except comments
Column 3 is for comments.

Here's the HTML code for the Thank You page:

```css
#columncontainer {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#column1 {
  float: left;
  width: 240px;
}

#column2 {
  float: left;
  width: 480px;
}

#column3 {
  float: left;
  width: 240px;
}

#footer {
  clear: both;
}

#image {
  margin-left: auto;
}

#columncontainer {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<h1>Thank you for your information.</h1>
<h3>Below is your profile information.</h3>

<div id="columncontainer">
  <div id="column1">

    all column 1 data here
    <figure>propic.png <figcaption>Profile Pic</figcaption> </figure>
  </div>

  <div id="column2">
    <hr>
    all column 2 data here
    <hr>
  </div>

  <div id="column3">
    all column 3 data here
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I improve these pages?

Answer (score 0):

below code as per your requirement:

**NOTE** : Change background color and border color as you want.

```
<div class="main-div">
    <header>
        <h1>Thank you for your information.</h1>
        <h3>Below is your profile information.</h3>
        <hr>
    </header>
    <div id="columncontainer">
        <div id="column1">
            <div class="div-col1">
            all column 1 data here
            <figure>propic.png <figcaption>Profile Pic</figcaption> </figure>
        </div>
        </div>

        <div id="column2">
            <div class="div-col2">
            all column 2 data here
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="column3">
            all column 3 data here
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
    header{
    text-align: center;
}
.main-div {
    background: #ececec; /*change background color here*/
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-height: 550px; /*minimum page height*/
    height: auto;
}
#column1, #column2, #column3{
    float: left;
    padding: 0 9px;
}
#column1, #column3{
    width: 25%;
}
#column2 {
    width: 44%;
}
.div-col1{
    border: 1px solid #ccc; /*change border color*/
    padding: 5px;
}
.div-col2{
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc; /*change border color*/
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; /*change border color*/
    padding: 5px;
}
#footer {
    clear: both;
}
#image {
    margin-left: auto;
}
```